# setOnSeekCompleteListener for VideoView how can be achieved 

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-video-player

I'm developing a video player application for which the user has an option to seek to a particular location, but the problem is there is no `setOnSeekCompleteListener` for VideoView,

So I am not sure if the seek operation that was requested has completed or not, and whether to start playback if it is complete.

Is there a way to implement a `setOnSeekCompleteListener` with VideoView.

Thanks,
Shrikant.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch from using `VideoView` to using `MediaPlayer` and a `SurfaceView`.

Or, grab the source code to `VideoView` (which is simply a combination of `MediaPlayer` and a `SurfaceView`) and modify it to expose the `MediaPlayer` `setOnSeekCompleteListener()`.

Comment: Mark Murphy sir, required your help in implementing seekTo(), right now its getting a time to play video back from the same position where it was left. Vitamio is not available. Can this solution be helpful? stackoverflow.com/a/9103715/379693