# How to play video upto specific time, from main video in android

Tags: android

```
public class MergeVideo extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myfirstpage);
        VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
        myVideoView.setVideoPath("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2video/files/a.mp4");
        myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        myVideoView.seekTo(6000);
        myVideoView.start();
    }
}
```

this is my code for play video . i have one main video file  19 second length i want to play video  from 6 second to 12 second i am able to start video from  6 second . i don't know how to stop video play on 12 sec please suggest me how implement this .

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) regarding canSeek* and seekTo?

Comment: which method  even i applied canseektoMethod also but there no time is there @M.Mimpen

Comment: You can start a new thread, that check current player position once a 500ms for example. And if position equals 12 sec it stops video play.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9103715/2389078) answer will implement what @kara4k suggested

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/hcVQBZA5VATmf9gfcQJVym  that also i have tried but i am unable to get  call back in run method

Comment: what is the max value for `currentPosition`. I think your if condition is going wrong.

Comment: total length 19 second i have to play from 6 to 12 second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested this, but it should work in your case.

```
 private VideoView mVideoView;
    private boolean mShouldStop = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
        mVideoView.setVideoPath("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2video/files/a.mp4");
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.seekTo(6000);
        mVideoView.start();
        trackProgress();
    }

    private void trackProgress() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!mShouldStop) {
                    if (mVideoView != null && mVideoView.isPlaying()) {
                        if (mVideoView.getCurrentPosition() >= 12000) {
                            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
                            mShouldStop = true;
                        }
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the [VideoView documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) doesn't have hooks for this, let's take a step back: what do we want to do?

1. Play the video (already done)
2. After x amount of time, stop the video **(to do)**

## Implement a timer

We want to play a video for an amount of time, then stop the video. Why not implement a [Timer (see documentation)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)?
On this timer, you can schedule a task to be performed.

One caveat: Don't forget to `cancel()` the timer. Otherwise it'll keep calling the method to pause/stop the video.