# Start video after few seconds

Tags: android

I have tried to play video file from sdcard. Initially I need to start playing media from 00:00:03. Guide me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default `VideoView` doesn't support `seek` functionality.

You can either **[make your own custom video view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063071/setonseekcompletelistener-for-videoview-how-can-be-achieved)** or **[use this library](http://vov.io/vitamio/#how-devs)** suggested in one answer already.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MediaPlayer use the seekTo(int). Note that the argument will be in milliseconds.

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) for more information.

Comment: I am using videoview only.On that I had used seekTo.But that's not working... :(